# iOS5 memory management with dispatch queues

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Now that there is ARC You cannot create a new NSAutoRelease pool... yet it leaks a bunch of memory if run on a different queue... should this be happening?

Comment: @Justin is correct, but I'm not sure I understand the "yet it leaks a bunch of memory" comment. I don't generally think of autorelease pools as a way to fix leaks, but rather allow the developer to dictate precisely when autoreleased items get their final release and are cleaned up. If you're leaking, you have to just fix those leaks. But perhaps I'm reading too much into your comment about "leaks a bunch of memory". Perhaps you were just talking about the peak memory utilization being too high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they merely changed how it is created, and forced this change on you for new development when ARC is enabled:

```
 @autoreleasepool { /* your autoreleasing program here */ }
```

`NSAutoreleasePool`s aren't really objects anymore.